# Why does Same Source Code generates different Map (Memory addresses) and elf file?

Tags: c, hex, memory-mapping

I have 2 exact same source codes which are under 2 different project names.

They generate the same output hex file, but the map file and elf files are different. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Have you done a `diff` to see how they differ?

Comment: I used Winmerge and it shows that the map files have differences. Under the  `*(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)` section ALL object files are listed and they show that they have different addresses.

Comment: have you resolved this problem?